# Android: What is the best technique?: Listview with data from sqlite editable

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, simplecursoradapter, custom-adapter

This is my first question. Let's see how it goes.
I'm a programmer but in a different language (ABAP4) and now I trying to do something with Android.

I have a table, with that table I have to fill a ListView, in the Activity where the ListView is there are some EditTexts at the top where I could change values from an item of the ListView, at the end I should take all the ListView updated info and update the table.

I filled the ListView with a SimpleCursorAdapter.
When I touch an item I can pass the values from the item (taken from the cursor) to the EditTexts at the top, and I can update the TextViews of the Item of the ListView, but only the views, not the Cursor.

Since I want to update the DB at some point, should I better select the data with the cursor, then fill an ArrayList and then fill the ListView? Then update the ArrayList with the new data and then update the DB? If so, should I use a custom Adapter?

Or could I keep using the Cursor? I don't get how to keep working with the Cursor. Can I update values in the cursor to use it later to update the DB?